What words do and do not admit a reduplicated (plural) version?
In this answer, Boaz Yaniv mentions that reduplication "...only works with short word, usually those one-kanji and one or two morae long." Wikipedia says there is a short list of nouns which admit reduplication.
Do we have such a list of reduplicated nouns and whether they indicate plural or not?
I am not talking about mimetics such as ふかふか and the like, but specifically words like 花々, 人々, 色々 and so on. Are there exceptions to the general criteria laid out above? Is there a way to make it more precise?

It's hard to get a decent list, but: https://tkuir.lib.tku.edu.tw/dspace/handle/987654321/29229, https://www.researchgate.net/publication/314238727_Xxingdieyunogouzaoshiyongyiweitexing-xiandairibenyushukiyanyejunhengkopasuwoyongitajiliangdediaozha-, https://repository.dl.itc.u-tokyo.ac.jp/records/27502, https://togaku.repo.nii.ac.jp/records/291

Thanks, it's for referencing work so this is good.
